# htaccess rewrite not taking away www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an .htaccess file that I want to do two simple things.

1. I want all of my pages to show up as https (this is working fine).
2. When someone goes to my site, no matter how they type in my site address, I want it to come up as https://example.com.

The reason being is whenever someone goes to my site with www. it causes them to have to try logging in twice to be able to access their account. It causes a new session when hitting 'Log in" and re-directs back to the index page.

If someone goes to my site with typing in the broswer bar... https://example.com or example.com ...it works just as it should.

This is my current .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

How can my .htaccess file remove the www. to rid this issue I am having?

Comment: you're only checking for `http://www`. `https://www` would have port 443, and fail that one `Cond`, causing everything else to bail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, This can be done with less code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```